# Firebase: Get all providers of a user

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to get all providers of a signed in user in an app that uses firebase as its backend. Is this possible?

The problem is, that I have a `facebookLogin` inside the app and I want it to disappear if the user is signed in via facebook or has facebook set as one of his providers. So for this is I need to know if the user has set facebook as one of his providers even if he is signed it via email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [getProviderData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getProviderData()):

```
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Provider: " + profile.getProviderId());
    }
```

Described in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_a_users_provider-specific_profile_information).

Comment: hey does it gives you the provider specific email in the for loop? 
In my case provider id is available but the email is not available.